# Undesirable dim light of LEDs on 7 segment display

Tags: transistors, 7segmentdisplay, python

I have a 7 segment display (common cathode) with 2 LEDs in each segment, powered by 12V, each segment controlled with a transistor (NPN) and Raspberry Pi 3.3V GPIO (and 4026 IC). What could be the reason(s) of unwanted dim light of unused segments, mainly at numbers where only few segments are in use theoretically, so at 1 for example two in use, but five are not and give dim light (also a little at 4), but the others look ok. I think there is no problem with the base resistor (27 kΩ and looks good with 54 kΩ and 81 kΩ too), BUT the segments are on the emitter side, does this explain the problem?
I'm not sure it is enough, but I have uploaded a part of the schematic. Now only this part is soldered on the PCB.

[image: schematic part]

This is the simple code I am using now only for test purposes (it works and counts and starts again):

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep


GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.OUT, initial=0)

sleep(1)

try:
    while True:
        GPIO.output(17, GPIO.HIGH)
        sleep(0.1)
        GPIO.output(17, GPIO.LOW)
        sleep(0.9)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    input("Press enter to quit\n\n")

GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: `powered by 12V, each segment controlled with a transistor (NPN) and Raspberry Pi 3.3V GPIO (and 4026 IC).` better to put a schematic instead. Also give some details about how you are driving the display i.e. multiplexed (at what frequency) or direct, etc. Even source code helps us to understand.

Comment: I don't think segments being emitter side is the problem.  I usually connect segments to emitter sides of the transistors and I haven't had any issues before. I thing you should add the PCB design or the schematic for us to understand the problem better.

Comment: You should provide a link to the data sheet, like https://components101.com/ics/ic-cd4026-pinout-circuit-datasheet  or  https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4026b.pdf?ts=1684742487564&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FCD4026B It looks like the "B" version can drive LED segments directly with 2-6 mA, so please provide a schematic to show where the transistors are connected.

Comment: Did you check it is not an optical problem with the display?

Comment: Is it 'ghosting' from a previously scanned digit?

Comment: @greybeard I think it works correctly.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany How do you mean scanned?

Comment: A very warm welcome to the site. Please note that it's a Q&A site, rather than a discussion forum, so a question should be written to provide a clear definition of your situation and problem, with a schematic for this question (not a photo of what's been built). The built-in schematic editor is simple and pretty quick to learn and use. Please edit your question and add this important detail before going any further into discussion, which can only be guesswork with the limited information presented. This will speed whatever progress will then be made. Thanks and, again, welcome.

Comment: Okay, if it's not a multiplexed display you'll need to supply the schematic so we're not guessing.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany It is the 1st digit of 6.

Comment: I would read the datasheet of the display carefully, look for the recommended display current and adjust the resistors between the LEDs and the transistors accordingly. If the LED current is too small, the LEDs are very dim.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the driver transistors are not turning off all the way.

On the 5th page of the [data sheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4026b.pdf) it shows connections for common cathode displays using emitter followers to drive the segments, and for common anode displays using common emitter drivers. While the common anode version uses base resistors, the common cathode, which is what you are using, does not. It also gives the formula for calculating the current limiting resistors. You could try following the data sheet circuit and see if that solves the problem.

Also you are running the counter on 3.3 V, so there's not going to be a lot of headroom for the LEDs. With emitter followers you need the base voltage to be the \$V_{LED} + V_{BE} + (I_{LED}*R)\$, so for example if the LED voltage is 2 V, base emitter voltage is 0.7 V, you've can't have more than 0.6 V across the resistor, for a 1k resistor that means the LED current would be 0.6 mA.

You might think that the 12 V supply would determine the LED brightness but it's drive voltage from the counter and the resistor that determines the LED current.

Comment: You were right, it works without base resistor (tested on one segment), but the symptom is the same. And it seems all digits' brightness is different (where different number of segments needed).

Comment: @solari see the addition to my answer.

Comment: Running the counter on 5V it looks better, unneeded dim lights cannot be seen. However the brightness of the different digits are still different, but not that much. So, it seems using leds on emitter side needs diff. calculation than I have performed (only calculated for collector side) and maybe the datasheet of BC549C should to be studied more precisely as well. But as you stated correctly, the counter (and the transistor base) needs higher voltage.

Answer (score 0):

In the first place I thought, that this cannot work at all.
The supply of the CD4026 is 3.3 V only, so this is the maximum voltage at the base of each transistor.
If I subtract 0.5 V base/emitter drop, ignoring the 27 kohm, there is 2.8 V left for two LEDs and the resistor in the best case.
But a red LED has a forward voltage of around 1.8 V, so a minimum of 3.6 V is needed here, so none of the LEDs would ever light up.

However, you say it works in some way. But how?
Then I have seen, that the GND of the CD4026 and Raspby is not connected to GND of the 12 V supply! That explains the dim light effect, but it is very complex.

I assume here, that your 12V supply comes from a SMPS connected to the grid. They contain so called Y-capacitors between their output connector and the AC grid to suppress transformer coupled EMI. In my schematic they are V3 and C1.

Further I assume, that the 3.3 V supply has either a real ground connection or again some Y-capacitor. My point is: There is a quite large AC voltage between the two GND potentials.

To simulate the reverse breakdown of the base/emitter junction and the LEDs I added all these zener diodes in series with standard diodes (D5-D12).

The segment connected to Q1 receives a "high" from the CD4026, simulated via V1.
The segment connected to Q2 receives just a "low" via R3.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHynAA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The simulator shows indeed the different LED currents in both segment paths as you describe.

[image: Segment currents]

The voltages at the anodes of the LEDs show the clamping effect of the reverse breakdown of the transistors and LEDs.

[image]

I made many assumptions here and they may be all wrong, but they explain what you see and that you see something at all.

Comment: Nice and very detailed analysis, it can explain this behavior. Besides, I'm not sure how my DC supply works, it is a simple AC - DC converter. As I have written in my previous comment, it looks better with 5V (but not perfect), would be good to test/simulate with 6-7-8... Volts or with another DC supply, but I think I'm going to try CA led display on collector side.

Comment: CA display behaves the same on collector side.